# How to get more font weights from Google Fonts than what they provide (or, how does Figma do it)?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts

Looking at the [Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?query=lato) Google Font...

They provide font weights of 300, 400, 700 and 900.

If I use the provided links/stylesheet or attach the font files directly, I can only use those sizes. If I try something like:

```
.text {
    font-weight: 500;  // Weight not provided by GF
}
```

it displays the same as `400`. And if I try with `600` it displays the same as `700`.

But using the exact same font files, I have much more granularity when doing my design in Figma. They are using the file that I provided to them, with only the limited set of weights. But I can switch through a dozen different sizes (thin, x-light, light... ) and each one has a distinctly different weight than the others.

Figma runs in the browser, so there is clearly a way to emulate the in-between weights somehow.

So, to the point: How does Figma do it? How can I get the in-between weights that I used in my (browser-based) design in Figma, but can't seem to do via CSS?

Comment: if you select a variable font you will have access to different weight, spaces... search for google variable fonts, and way to use them in website (by the way, lot better, file lot smaller than 3, 4 or... 6 weight files). If you have fixed weight, you are glued with the weight you have downloaded.

Comment: Right, but my designs in Figma are using the font files I uploaded - not variable fonts - and they seem to be able to display all the non-standard weights. So they're faking it some how.

Comment: certainly as if you're using Illustrator, you can play with fonts. That meaning it's not a direct rendering, there is a "virtual" space where image, vector image, is rendered using their own parameters, and after it's rendered on your screen. That's very common for any design software (bitmap or vector). To use directly in html/css, the variable font solution is good. You have several options not available in fix font, and you have to link 1 font file instead of several